The form of linear operator on an infinite dimensional normed space
Consider the linear operators on the normed space $l^p$, where the norm is $||x||=(\sum_\limits{\nu = 1}^\infty|x_\nu|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$,  $x=\{x_\nu\}$. Define $T$ as follows: when $x=\{x_\nu\}$, $Tx=\{y_\mu\}$, where $y_\mu = \sum_\limits{\nu=1}^\infty t_{\mu\nu}x_\nu, \mu=1,2,\cdots$. Then if $t_{\mu\nu}$satisfies some inequation, $T$ is a bounded linear operator.
My question is: is every linear operator of this form? And is every bounded linear operator of this form?
I defined $e_\nu=\{0,\cdots,0,1,0,\cdots\}$, then $x = \{x_\nu\}=\sum_\limits{\nu=1}^\infty x_\nu e_\nu$. But can I derive that $T(x)=\sum_\limits{\nu = 1}^\infty x_\nu T(e_\nu)$? Since the definition of linear operators is just finite sum.

I am just beginning learning functional analysis and have little idea of linear operators on infinite vector spaces

Assume $T$ is a bounded operator $\ell^p$ into itself. Thus $$Tx=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \varphi_i(x)e_i$$ for some coefficients $\varphi_i(x)$ which satisfy $\sum_{i=1}^\infty |\varphi_i(x)|^p<\infty.$ The mapping $x\mapsto \varphi_k(x)$ is a bounded linear functional on $\ell^p$ because $|\varphi_k(x)|\le \|Tx\|_p.$ Hence
$$\varphi_k(x)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty t_{kj}x_j,\quad \sum_{j=1}^\infty |t_{kj}|^q<\infty, \ k\in \mathbb{N}$$ where $p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1.$ Therefore
$$Tx=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\left (\sum_{j=1}^\infty t_{ij}x_j\right )e_i$$ hence
$$(Tx)_i=\sum_{j=1}^\infty t_{ij}x_j \quad (*)$$ Thus the operator $T$ has the desired form.
Observe that for $x=e_k$ we have
$(Te_k)_i=t_{ik}.$ Therefore $\sum_{i=1}^\infty |t_{ik}|^p<\infty.$ So the columns of $T$ are $p$ summable while the rows are $q$ summable.
We have $\sum_{i=1}^nx_ie_i\underset{n}{\to} x.$ By continuity of $T$ we get
$$\sum_{i=1}^nx_iTe_i=T\left (\sum_{i=1}^nx_ie_i\right )\underset{n}{\to}Tx$$ Thus the series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_iTe_i$ is convergent and $\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_iTe_i=Tx.$
If $T$ is unbounded the operator may not admit the expected form. For example let $\varphi$ be an unbounded linear functional on $\ell^p$ such that $\varphi(e_k)=0$ for any $k.$ Let $Tx=\varphi(x)e_1.$ Then $ Te_k=0$ for any $k.$ Therefore the formula $(*)$ is not valid. Indeed assume $(*($ holds. Then $$0=(Te_k)_i=t_{ik}$$ Thus
$t_{ij}=0$ for all $i,j$ but $T\neq 0,$ a contradiction.
